# Using string as file input to subprocess

Tags: python, file, subprocess, pipe

I'm trying to pipe a file input through subprocess.PIPE:

The first pipe I tried is working, as follows:

```
sanitizer_args = ['java', '-Xmx'+args.memory , '-cp', args.jar, 'org.genemania.plugin.apps.GeneSanitizer', '--data', args.dataset, '--organism', args.organism]
p = subprocess.Popen(sanitizer_args, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
sanitized, errors = p.communicate(input = sanitizer_input)
```

Which works fine - the second one, in the exact same fashion, fails:

```
query_args = ['java', '-Xmx'+args.memory, '-cp', args.jar, 'org.genemania.plugin.apps.QueryRunner', '--data', args.dataset, '--threads', args.threads, '--out', 'scores', '--results', args.results]
genequeryfile = '\n'.join([args.organism, final_querygenes, args.networks, '100', args.weighting])
q = subprocess.Popen(query_args, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
results, query_errors = q.communicate(input = genequeryfile)
```

I do know that the second subprocess is able to take multiple inputs - does this factor in my problem at all?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please explain what is failing.  Does an error occur?  If so, please copy and paste the traceback that is printed out.  Also, what is `sanitizer_input`?

Comment: sanitizer_input is the input I'm piping to the subprocess in the first case. Correction: an error does not occur, the subprocess simply completes without having received any file input.

Comment: I mean, how does the form of `sanitizer_input` compare to `genqueryfile`?  You haven't shown how `sanitizer_input` is created, so it's difficult so compare how the two calls are different.

Comment: My bad - they are both strings that conform to the subprocesses' requirements. The peculiar thing is that if I run the second subprocess in the shell without any file inputs, it returns the same output as it does when I try to pipe the string input to it using the subprocess module.

Comment: Silly question, but does the second call expect input?  Or, does the same behavior happen when you call the second one one the command line and not within python?

Comment: If you can afford to install the sh module, see http://amoffat.github.io/sh/#piping